# Disabling use of arrow movement in radios and text boxes in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, textbox

I am using radio buttons and text boxes on the same stage as a character that is controlled by the arrow keys. When I click a radio and press the arrow keys, the keys register as changing between radios, and not as moving the character. When selecting the text box, the arrows move both the cursor and the character, but now, as I am trying to add an action triggered by the spacebar, it is only triggered in the text box.

Is there anyway of preventing the arrows and spacebar from being triggered aside from preventDefault, which does not seem to be working?

Comment: Are you using TextFields, TextAreas or TextInputs? Are you wanting the user to input text into them or are you simply displaying information in them?

Answer (score 2):

`radioName.focusEnabled = false;` on all your radio buttons should solve your radio issue.

For the 'Text', if you are simply displaying info with them I would make them non-select-able TextFields.

If you want a user to input into them at the same time as moving a character around with the arrow keys this seems problematic since users expect text inputs to behave certain ways when arrow and space keys are pressed. I would recommend having them on a different movieClip that is summoned by a button on your main screen. Once they are done inputing the text then return to your character.